# histogram without vertical lines in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, histogram

I am trying to make an histogram without vertical lines. I'd like to have a plot which looks like a  function. Like this:
[image]

The same question has been asked for R before ( [histogram without vertical lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030684/histogram-without-vertical-lines) ) but I'm on Mathematica.

I have been looking into the `ChartStyle` options without success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There probably are ways to do this by fiddling with `EdgeForm[]` and `FaceForm[]` in `Histogram`, but I've found it simpler to roll one on my own, whenever I need it. Here's a very simple and quick example:

```
histPlot[data_, bins_, color_: Blue] := Module[{
        countBorder = 
    Partition[Riffle[Riffle[#1, #1[[2 ;;]]], Riffle[#2, #2]], 2] & @@ 
     HistogramList[data, bins, "PDF"]
    },
    ListLinePlot[countBorder, PlotStyle -> color]
    ]
```

Doing `histPlot[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[],{1000}],{-3,3,0.1}]` gives

[image]

You can then extend this to take any option instead of just `"PDF"`, and for cases when you'd like to choose the bins automatically. I dislike automatic binning, because I like to control my bin widths and extents for predictability and easy comparison against other plots.

Comment: Thank you yoda and Heike for your help. Yoda, Your self-contained function works very well.

Answer (score 6):

You could also use `ListPlot` with `InterpolationOrder->0`:

```
(* example data *)
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 10^3];

hist = HistogramList[data, {.5}];

ListPlot[Transpose[{hist[[1]], ArrayPad[hist[[2]], {0, 1}, "Fixed"]}],
  InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
  Joined -> True, 
  AxesOrigin -> {hist[[1, 1]], 0}]
```

[image: histogram]

Comment: @tos For versions older than 8, you can use `BinCounts` (needs a little extra work)

Comment: Thank you Heike for your input. @Szabolcs, I didn't mention I am using version 8, but the tip is handy for users of pre-8 versions.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two methods that work in version 7, using post-processing:

```
rdat = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200];
```

```
MapAt[
  {Blue,
   Line[# /. {{Rectangle[{x_, y_}, {X_, Y_}]}} :> Sequence[{x, Y}, {X, Y}]] } &,
  Histogram[rdat, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"],
  {1, 2, 2, 2}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Cases[
  Histogram[rdat, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"],
  Rectangle[{x_, y_}, {X_, Y_}] :> {{x, Y}, {X, Y}},
  \[Infinity]
];

Graphics[Line[Join @@ %], AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That's pretty close to what I was using in v7 before I upgraded. I don't think these will work in v8, as there have been changes to `Histogram`